# Why Windows' tracert command maximum hops is limited to 255?

Tags: cmd, routes

When using the the -h flag of the 'tracert' command on Windows, I cannot go beyond 255. I wanted to know why is it limited to 255? Is a route of 256+ hops not possible or does 255 mean "unlimited"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field used in the IP packet header has 8 bits, so maximum value is 255.